# How to add css class on validation error to list item

Tags: java, wicket

In my application I have ListView with textField which is validating when user submit button. When there is error it will show error message. Problem is there is a lot of rows so user can not recognize bad row easily. So is there some way how to add css class to this bad row after submitting button ?

```
    private void addListView() {
        add(new PropertyListView<MyClass>("view") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(final ListItem<MyClass> listItem) {


                listItem.add(new TextField<String>("result") {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    @Override
                    public final <String> IConverter<MyClass> getConverter(Class<MyClass> type) {
                        return (IConverter<MyClass>) StringConverter.getInstance();
                    }

                });         

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [FormComponent#isValid()](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponent.html#isValid()) to tell if a component has validation errors. 
Then you can add a CSS class in the `onBeforeRender()`.

See here for inspiration: (note it is Wicket 1.4 so you might need to change small bits):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Automatic+styling+of+form+errors

Of course you can also find the `findParent()` of the Component to find the row..

Answer (score 0):

thanks to RobAu answer I just need to override validate method in textField:

```
                    public void validate() {
                        super.validate();
                        if (!isValid()) {
                            add(new AttributeModifier("class", "errorField"));
                        }
                    };
```

Comment: Wouldn't that stay on the component after you fixed and error?

Comment: hm it will stay there until I submit form with valid value what is good for me